# How does one prove L'Hôpital's rule?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

L'Hôpital's rule  can be stated as follows:

> Let $f, g$ be differentiable real functions defined on a deleted one-sided neighbourhood$^{(1)}$ of $a$, where $a$ can be any real number or $\pm \infty$. Suppose that both $f,g$ converge to $0$ or that both $f,g$ converge to $+\infty$ as $x \to a^{\pm}$ ($\pm$ depending on the side of the deleted neighbourhood). If
>   $$\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} \to L,$$
>   then 
>   $$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \to L,$$
>   where $L$ can be any real number or $\pm \infty$.

This is an ubiquitous tool for computations of limits, and some books avoid proving it or just prove it in some special cases. Since we don't seem to have a consistent reference for its statement and proof in MathSE and it is a theorem which is often misapplied (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1710786/) for an example), it seems valuable to have a question which could serve as such a reference. This is an attempt at that.

$^{(1)}$E.g., if $a=1$, then $(1,3)$ is such a neighbourhood.

Comment: Don't know whether it helps but it may worth note that some books defines the limit of a function on a point on the intersection of a deleted (one-sided) neighbourhood and the domain of the function. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2953437) for discussions. Anyway, it does not affect the proof, but the statement of the theorem.

Comment: For reference, it might be important to add the hypothesis that both $g$ and $g'$ should be nonzero in such a neighbourhood.

Comment: @Izralbu That $g'$ is nonzero in such a neighbourhood is already contained in the hypothesis that $\frac{f'}{g'} \to L$. That $g$ is also nonzero in a neighbourhood is part of the conclusion, and also implicit when we say $\frac{f}{g} \to L$.

Answer (score 12):

For the sake of avoiding clutter, we suppose without loss of generality that $x \to a^+$ and establish the notation that a "neighbourhood" refers to a deleted one-sided neighbourhood.

Pick $\epsilon>0$. By hypothesis, there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $a$ such that $g'(x) \neq 0$ for every $x \in U$ and
$$L-\epsilon<\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}<L+\epsilon \tag{1}$$ 
for every $x \in U$. By the [Cauchy mean value theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchysMean-ValueTheorem.html), it follows that for every $\alpha, \beta \in U$ with $\beta>\alpha$,
$$L-\epsilon<\frac{f(\beta)-f(\alpha)}{g(\beta)-g(\alpha)}<L+\epsilon. \tag{2}$$

We divide the proof now in order to address our two main cases.

***Case 1:*** $f,g \to 0$ as $x \to a^+$.

By letting $\alpha \to a$ in $(2)$, we have that
$$L-\epsilon \leq \frac{f(\beta)}{g(\beta)}\leq L+\epsilon.$$
Since this holds for every $\beta \in U$, we have the result in this case.

OBS: Note that $g(\beta)\neq 0$ due to the mean value theorem applied to $g$ extended continuously to $a$. In fact, one could also apply the Cauchy mean value theorem to the extensions of $f$ and $g$ in order to prove this case by considering $\frac{f(\beta)-f(0)}{g(\beta)-g(0)}$ directly. Of course, this would not work in the case where $f,g \to +\infty$.

***Case 2:*** $f,g \to +\infty$ as $x \to a^+$.

We can rewrite $(2)$ as
$$L-\epsilon<\frac{f(\beta)}{g(\beta)-g(\alpha)}  + \frac{g(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)-g(\beta)} \cdot\frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)}<L+\epsilon.$$
Taking the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ as $\alpha \to a$ together with the fact that $g \to +\infty$ yields
$$L-\epsilon \leq \liminf_{\alpha \to a}\frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)} \leq \limsup_{\alpha \to a}\frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)} \leq L+\epsilon.$$
Since this holds for every $\epsilon>0$, we have that $\liminf_{\alpha \to a}\frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)} = \limsup_{\alpha \to a}\frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)}=L$ and the result follows.

---

Some observations:

- It should also be clear that if $L = +\infty$ (resp. $-\infty$), then these proofs can be easily adapted by changing "pick $\epsilon>0$" to "pick $K \in \mathbb{R}$" and changing inequality $(1)$ to $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} >K$  (resp. $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} < K$), while also making the obvious following changes.
- As a mild curiosity (which is not so deep after some inspection), note that in the case of $f,g \to +\infty$, the assumption that $f \to  +\infty$ is actually not necessary. It suffices to assume that $g \to  +\infty$. But stating the theorem without assuming $f \to +\infty$ may be confusing to students that see this much more frequently in the context of the so-called "indeterminate forms".
- The passage involving the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ may be somewhat obscure. First of all, we are adopting the following definitions:
  $$\limsup_{x \to a} = \inf_{\substack{\text{$U$ del.} \\ \text{nbhd. of $x$}}}  \sup_{x \in U} f(x), \quad \liminf_{x \to a} = \sup_{\substack{\text{$U$ del.} \\ \text{nbhd. of $x$}}}  \inf_{x \in U} f(x).$$
  We could also solve that part sequentially by taking $x_n \to a$ and using the [$\limsup$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SupremumLimit.html) and [$\liminf$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfimumLimit.html) of sequences, establishing that the limit is the same for every sequence $x_n \to a$. It is a matter of preference.

  Then, we are using are the following facts:

  1) If $\lim_{x \to a} h(x) = M$, then
  $$\limsup (h(x)+j(x)) = M +\limsup j(x) $$
  and
  $$\liminf (h(x)+j(x)) = M +\liminf j(x) .$$
    2) If $\lim_{x \to a} h(x) = c >0$, then
  $$\limsup (h(x) j(x)) = c \cdot\limsup j(x)$$
  and 
  $$\liminf (h(x) j(x)) = c \cdot\liminf j(x).$$
    3) If $h(x) \leq j(x)$, then
  $$\limsup h(x) \leq \limsup j(x) $$
  and
  $$\liminf h(x) \leq \liminf j(x) .$$
    4) $\liminf h(x) \leq \limsup h(x)$ and, if both coincide, then $\lim h(x)$ exists and is equal to both.

Comment: In case 2, it might be helpful to note that $$ \frac{g(\alpha)}{g(\alpha) - g(\beta)} = 1 + \frac{g(\beta)}{g(\alpha) - g(\beta)}. $$ Otherwise, one might be tempted to use L'Hôpital to find the limit of the left-hand side. This would be a terrible mistake, of course.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, $f'(a) = \lim_\limits{x\to a} \frac {f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}$

if $f'(a), g'(a)$ exist and $g'(a) \ne 0$

$\frac {f'(a)}{g'(a)} = \lim_\limits{x\to a} \dfrac {\frac {f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}}{\frac {g(x) - g(a)}{x-a}} =  \lim_\limits{x\to a}\frac {f(x) - f(a)}{g(x) - g(a)}$

if $f(a), g(a) = 0$

$\frac {f'(a)}{g'(a)} = \lim_\limits{x\to a}\frac {f(x) }{g(x)}$

Comment: Saying that $f'(x)/g'(x) = \lim_{x \to a} (something(x))$ does not make much sense. (Briefly speaking, the later is a constant, the former something that depends on $x$.) You can fix this strategy by using some form of mean-value theorem, but this still leaves the case of $f,g \to +\infty$ unattended.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo you are absolutely correct.  Thanks, I have corrected what I was trying to say.